# add a small bar below UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I want to use many bars like this one in my app (i don't know how to name it : the bar that contains "The Early Show" "48 Hours").

Is there a simple way to create something like this ? What are the basic objects to use ?
Thanks.

[bar from CBS app http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/056/Purple/38/9f/8a/mzl.bqhasrjw.320x480-75.jpg](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/056/Purple/38/9f/8a/mzl.bqhasrjw.320x480-75.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AKAIK, there is nothing in the SDK that does this for you.  However, a UIScroll view, with some custom UIButons and a nifty mask image could be used to reproduce something like what you've shown in the screenshot.

Something like this: http://blog.sallarp.com/iphone-sliding-menu/

Comment: So, how about accepting this as the correct answer to your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

.h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

@property ( nonatomic , retain )  IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender;

-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons;
```

.m

```
@synthesize scrollView;



-(void)AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:(id)sender{


    NSLog(@"AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom called");


    UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;


    if (button.tag == 0) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    }
    else if (button.tag == 1) {

        NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);

    }
    // ......like this

    NSLog(@"button clicked is : %iBut \n\n",button.tag);



}       



-(void)createMenuWithButtonSize:(CGSize)buttonSize withOffset:(CGFloat)offset noOfButtons:(int)totalNoOfButtons{

for (int i = 0; i < totalNoOfButtons; i++) {

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(AppleVijayAtFacebookDotCom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        //[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with image

        //OR

    [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%iBut",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//with title

    button.frame = CGRectMake(i*(offset+buttonSize.width), 8.0, buttonSize.width, buttonSize.height);

    button.clipsToBounds = YES;

    button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted=YES;

    button.layer.cornerRadius = 10;//half of the width

    button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

    button.tag=i;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

}

self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake((buttonSize.width + offset) * totalNoOfButtons, buttonSize.height);

    //self.navigationItem.titleView=self.scrollView;//if u have navigationcontroller then enable this line
```

}

**Dont forget to connect the scrollView in interface builder**

**while creating the scrollview in IB make sure ur scrollView height is 44.which is default to navigation bar.so it will look nice.**

```
in viewDidLoad call 

[self createMenuWithButtonSize:CGSizeMake(70.0, 30.0) withOffset:20.0f noOfButtons:30];
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]